# Overflow expands div unexpectedly?

Tags: html, css, layout, frontend

excuse me if my question will be naive but i'm just learning some basic HTML and CSS from home.

I'm trying to understand how the overflow works. I've read a lot online but still i can't get a firm grip on it...in the specific why should i use

```
overflow: hidden;
```

in order to get my div to expand on top and get rid of the white space?

BEFORE:
[div not expanding properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEsxz.jpg)

AFTER:
[div expanding on top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVTlF.jpg)

Here you can see my code which is almost the same: https://codepen.io/Code_Cafe/pen/EemVRz

My answer has been marked as "answered". The fact is that I've read about collapsing margins but i didn't understand the explanation and most of all, WHY `overflow:hidden` is the solution...

Many thanks guys!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Will you please share your html and css code snippet?

Comment: a lot of reasons: overflow clear float, change the baseline of inline-block, etc etc ... share your code to get the answer

Comment: I've uploaded the code, sorry!

Comment: there is nothing in your code similar to what we see in the image

Comment: Nothing? I don't what are you looking at, but the code is almost the same except for the navbar which i have removed for simplicity.
If in the code you type overflow:hidden; in the .container then you will notice that it changes and i can't explain why...